# How do I sort links based on their popularity?

Tags: html, sorting, popularity

This might look a little noobish, but after a lot of research, I am asking this. I'd like to make a page, which will have links to different pages inside. Like this http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/ I basically want them to arrange themselves with the hits they get. I am not using wordpress, hence I do not know where and how to go. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: overall hits or each time they get clicked the move to top of page?

Comment: If you don't use a CMS, what languages do you know?

Comment: Overall hits. 

I am good at HTML, and CSS. And I know it cannot be achieved using HTML and CSS. Isn't there any plugin or something which I can use for this?

Comment: Or is there any plugin of wordpress, which sorts pages depending on the hits it gets? The inner pages will not be on wordpress though.

Comment: If you're not using wordpress, how would a WP plugin help?

Comment: I can use WP for the main page, and add inner links as the non WP ones.